# Username or Password : Why every email provider specifies like this? Is there any specific reason?

Tags: java, email, authentication, passwords

when any person enters wrong username or password, generally any ***email provider*** tells that

**"your email-id or password is incorrect"** .

And, why cant they specifically tell **"your email-id  is incorrect"** or **"your  password is incorrect"** or **"your email-id and password both are incorrect"**

Is there any reason behind this.. or this is just by design they had implemented..

***Can any body explain this...***

Comment: No. You are free to write anything. But, by being specific about what is wrong the probability bad thing increases...

Comment: That is not a question regarding Java or servlet.

Answer (score 4):

It's a security thing.

If someone (or something) is trying to brute force an entry, they (hopefully) don't have any indication of the data, e.g. usernames. By saying password incorrect you are giving an indication that that username exists and is a flag to say if you keep trying a password here, you could eventually get it right.

Where as if you say username or password incorrect there is no indication if that's a valid username or not, making an attacks job more difficult.

Comment: Also, how would the server know you have a correct password without even knowing what account you tried to access? An account has a password, a password does not have an account. How would the server know if you simply misstyped one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

It is for security reason, if you are the owner of this e-mail, then you should know what is your ID, if exactly tell you that which one is in correct, then someone that is not the owner of this ID will sure that the ID is OK, then trying to find the password for this ID.

Answer (score 0):

It is a part of security. It is a good practice to show less error details to make the site more secure from hackers.